# i want to host my discord bot on heroku and i do everything correct but when i do git push heroku i get error in logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku, discord

I want to host my discord bot on Heroku but when i do git push heroku it says it's TypeError

But when i run my bot on my pc it works perfect.. so i don't understand what's problem with heroku..

Error:

````
2020-01-05T11:50:17.718173+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-01-05T11:50:17.636956+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot set property 'port' of undefined
2020-01-05T11:50:17.636975+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/config.js:149:19)
2020-01-05T11:50:17.636977+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
2020-01-05T11:50:17.636980+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
2020-01-05T11:50:17.636982+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
2020-01-05T11:50:17.636984+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
2020-01-05T11:50:17.636986+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
2020-01-05T11:50:17.636988+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2020-01-05T11:50:17.636990+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/index.js:44:16)
2020-01-05T11:50:17.636993+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
2020-01-05T11:50:17.636994+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
2020-01-05T11:50:17.705478+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think the app cannot bind to the given (hardcoded?) port and it fails.
Heroku runtime provides you with an environment variable PORT (upper case): you should use that to define the port of your app.